# How to mock value peer test in jest 26?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, jestjs, ts-jest

I would like to mock value `ENV_JWT_ENABLED` peer test. I would like to use `new value A` in first test and `new value B` in second test. But I am getting still `foo` from global mock.

My current solution not working.

```
import { JwtAuthGuard } from './jwt-auth.guard';

jest.mock('const/env', () => ({
    ENV_JWT_ENABLED: 'foo'
}));

describe('test', () => {
    it('A', () => {
        jest.mock('const/env', () => ({
            ENV_JWT_ENABLED: 'new value A'
        }));

        const instance = new JwtAuthGuard(); // will print foo inside
    });

    it('B', () => {
        jest.mock('const/env', () => ({
            ENV_JWT_ENABLED: 'new value B'
        }));

        const instance = new JwtAuthGuard(); // will print foo inside
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jest always prefered global vs within block, better using `mockImplementationOnce` with
`mockImplementation` provide you to mock value based on its call.
you can refer https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockimplementationoncefn chaining of mock for fn.

```js
import { JwtAuthGuard } from './jwt-auth.guard';

jest.mock('const/env', () => {
  return {
    ENV_JWT_ENABLED: jest
      .fn()
      .mockImplementation()
      .mockImplementationOnce(() => {
        return 'new value A';
      })
      .mockImplementationOnce(() => {
        return 'new value B';
      })
  };
});

describe('test', () => {
    it('A', () => {
        const instance = new JwtAuthGuard(); // will print new value A inside
    });

    it('B', () => {
        const instance = new JwtAuthGuard(); // will print new value B inside
    });
});
```

Comment: *jest always prefered global vs within block* - this is not true. It's easier to do that but this doesn't mean it's good. Jest has helpers for test-scoped module mocking. `mockImplementationOnce` inside `jest.mock` or `__mocks__` is certainly a bad practice because this results in test cross-contamination. A global mock with `mockImplementationOnce` assumes it will be consumed in specific sequence. If a way it's used in tests or the order of tests change, the mock will went wrong. Not to mention that ENV_JWT_ENABLED is not a function and cannot be mocked this way.

Answer (score 0):

`jest.mock` at test level cannot affect top-level imports. `jest.isolateModules` or `jest.resetModules` can be used in conjunction with `require` or dynamic `import` to provide test-specific module mocks:

```
it('A', () => {
  jest.isolateModules(() => {
    jest.mock('const/env', () => ({
        ENV_JWT_ENABLED: 'new value A'
    }));

    const { JwtAuthGuard } = require('./jwt-auth.guard');

    const instance = new JwtAuthGuard();
  });
});
```